# How to generate random number in FreePascal between 1 and 1,000,000

Tags: random, freepascal

How to generate random number in Free Pascal between 1 and 1,000,000?

I have used a variable type as LongInt, Real, Integer, but there is always an RangeError.

But random number between 1 and 33,333 is working correctly.

```
Program Random;

var
  a: ...;

begin

a:=random(1000000);

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Free Pascal do you use? I have no problems here with 2.6.0 and using **LongInt** as type for **a**.

BTW: You should not name your program **Random**, this leads to an error (but not to a range error).

Comment: Probably he uses integer, and in the default mode that's 16-bit. So the longint advise is good. Longint is 32-bit in all modes